# How to split character values in each row and create new columns in SQL

Tags: sql, transpose, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a field that consists of different strings of letters in each row:

```
BAAAAZZAFBF
AAAAAZZAFBA
FAZZZAA
```

I would like to output these rows into columns based on each character (one column would be B, the next would be A, etc.).

I have this query right now but only transposes rows to columns - does not separate them.

```
SELECT Primary Key,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE = 'B__________' THEN 1 END) B_Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE = 'A__________' THEN 2 END) A_Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE = 'F_______' THEN 3 END) F_name
  FROM TABLE
 GROUP BY Primary key
```

Output table would look like this with each section corresponding to a field in table:

Primary Key | A | B | D | Z | F

---

Comment: Please show the results that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT Primary Key,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE = 'B__________' THEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE END) as B_Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE = 'A__________' THEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE END) as A_Name,
       MAX(CASE WHEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE = 'F_______' THEN DNB_MATCH_GRADE END) as F_name
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Primary key
```